# Travis-CI badge not updating

Tags: travis-ci

I have retriggered a failed Travis-CI build for a public open source project yesterday. The build succeeded, however, the badge still shows "build failing", both on [GitHub](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json) and on [Travis-CI](https://travis-ci.org/ralfstx/minimal-json).

Is there anything I can do to refresh it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure about Travis-CI, but I know GitHub [aggresively caches](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/224) images. Once the cache goes stale you'll see the correct badge. Other than waiting there's not much you can do.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, waiting helped indeed. However, the GitHub caching does not explain why the badge was still red on the Travis-CI page as well, right? So in this case, it seems that some cache on the Travis side caused the issue.

Comment: I suspect the same (cache in Travis). It's often happened to me. I've been meaning to open an issue, but I figured the caching is intentional.

Answer (score 10):

The previous answer is so close! Github wouldn't be involved at all, all they do is link to the image with html. And I know from experience that Travis updates it basically immediately. It's actually browser side caching!

Your browser doesn't request the new image because it already has it. This is actually how all images work on the web. You can rest assured the correct build status is showing for new visitors to your repo.

If you need that green badge to show up for your own peace of mind, just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to purge the cache.

Comment: Another quick and easy way is to open private browsing / incognito. As an aside, this causes me to wonder how often I see various cached images instead of their updated versions. I wonder if having a fast enough internet connection would allow for less caching and hence more accurate images?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is not any connection speed that modifies chrome's caching behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As @icodesometime answered, it's more to the client's browser caching problem, dealing with the CDN's cookie.

If you get [image] even passing the TravisCI and reloading doesn't take effect, such as hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + reload or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> etc. in Chrome, then try:

1. Open Developer tools
2. Right-click on the reload/refresh button and select "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in Chrome on Mac solved this issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered that you can "bust" the GitHub cache by just adding insignificant content to the URL query string.  So while "https://img.shields.io/travis/numpy/numpy/master.svg" might be cached, "https://img.shields.io/travis/numpy/numpy/master.svg?x=1" probably isn't.  Or add "&x=1" at the end if there is already query string content.  Works for me for every badge type.  Note that you will want to change the value in that query string every time you need to bust the cache.